# How to write a template function that can handle object or pointer function calls ?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to be able to write a template function that can invoke a function call on all elements of a container. We can assume that the function name is always the same. However what isn't known is whether the container is holding objects or pointers. ie, whether I should de-reference.

```
template< typename TContainer >
void ProcessKeyedContainer( TContainer &keyedContainer )
{
  for ( auto it = keyedContainer.begin(); it != keyedContainer.end(); ++it )
  {
    // do some random stuff here.
    // ...

    auto value = it->second;
    value.Process(); // or value->Process() if the container has pointers
  }
}

...

std::map< int, CMyObject > containerOfObjects;
containerOfObjects[0] = CMyObject();

std::map< int, CMyObject* > containerOfPointers;
containerOfPointers[0] = new CMyObject();

// I would like both calls to look near identical
ProcessKeyedContainer( containerOfObjects ); 
ProcessKeyedContainer( containerOfPointers );
```

Is there a neat way to be able to make the Process call inside ProcessKeyedContainer, without putting a burden on the caller ( ie the caller doesn't have to know to use it in one way for pointers and another way for objects ), and without having to duplicate too much code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloaded function template is the savior:

```
template<typename T>
void invoke(T * obj)  //when object is pointer
{
      obj->Process();
}

template<typename T>
void invoke(T & obj)  //when object is non-pointer
{
      obj.Process();
}
```

then use it as:

```
auto value = it->second;
invoke(value); //correct invoke() will be selected by the compiler!
```

But that is not good enough, as you might want to do something else also with `value` in the rest of the function written by you. So if you follow the above approach, there will be code duplication, as both `invoke()` will have almost similar code.

So here is one improvement: instead of using `invoke()`, **turn the pointer into reference** so that you could use it uniformly in your function.

```
template<typename T>
T& ensure_ref(T * obj)  //when object is pointer
{
      return *obj; //return the dereferenced object
}

template<typename T>
T& ensure_ref(T & obj)  //when object is non-pointer
{
      return obj; //simply return it
}
```

And use it as:

```
auto & value = ensure_ref(it->second); //call ensure_ref to ensure reference!

value.Process(); //value is gauranteed to be NOT pointer!

//you might want to do this also!
value.xyz = abc;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1, and I would further refine this by taking iterators as the function arguments to `ProcessKeyedContainer()` rather than the container reference.

Comment: Thanks! The ensure_ref accomplishes exactly what I need.